# PHP exec sudo script not working despite having sudo rights

Tags: php, linux, exec, sudo

My php script:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);


exec('sudo /path/to/script.sh');
?>
```

my visudo line

```
www-data        ALL=NOPASSWD: /path/to/script.sh
```

(I tripled checked every path)

If i remove the 'sudo' in the exec() it will execute (i put a `touch aaa` at the start, with sudo the file isn't even created so the script doesn't even begin to execute). The script has exec rights for everyone.

I can't manage to get any error output. I can't su into www-data to try to launch it manually with sudo (when I su I get "This account is currently not available.
", but I guess that's normal behavior).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If your system has selinux or some other policy-based access control engine enabled, your web server process will be running under a constrained context which limits rights further. Verify whether you have selinux enabled.
2. Provide the full path to `sudo`. While your shell may have it in its path, perhaps your web server does not.

Answer (score 0):

1 -If you're working with RHEL/CentOS and the path is under the /root path you can't execute it.
2 - Check if the scrit have the 'x' flag (chmod +x /path/to/script.sh)
3 - Check if the user ww-data can execute the scrit with

```
sudo -u www-data script.sh
```